# escape from a parent css class in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working with an HTML template that has its own CSS and is quite extensive. It has over 2,000 lines of code. I want to put an input text with a button inside a form, but this form has a CSS class, since I don't want to modify the existing CSS class just for one button, is there a way to put an HTML element inside a form with a CSS class, such that the CSS class doesn't affect my HTML element? Are there any special HTML tags which I could use to put other elements inside element which wouldn't be affect by the CSS of the parent?

```
<form class="some-class">
  I want to put this elements inside the form but I don't want them to be affected by the form class:
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either give the element an ID attribute or use a Class Name that's not used anywhere else. Then you'll be able to set CSS styles for that ID or Class Name that will affect just that element only.

As far as the parent, the CSS classes attached to elements do not affect the parent element of that element. CSS classes only affect the element they are applied to and are used to dig down to elements within (cascading) that element.

Comment: Adding to this, if you have a global "default" theme class, you could override the default class on the form, and then immediately re-override the css class back to the "default" class for the input-group.

Answer (score 0):

By editing your current CSS, you can add a not() rule to the form CSS, assuming you have such.

For example, if you had:

```
form input { border: 2px solid red; }
```

Then you could add your class with the negation as in:

```
form:not(.some-class) input { border: 2px solid red; }
```

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) has more details about the `:not()` and shows you compatibility (IE 9+, for example.)

The other way around is to have a *positive* class on all forms, except the few that you do not want transformed:

```
<form class="form-xyz">...</form>

form.form-xyz input { border: 2px solid red; }
```

In most cases, that works *better*. Especially with older browsers. Also you do not have to specify the keyword `form`:

```
.form-xyz input { border: 2px solid red; }
```

But all of that mainly depends on your existing CSS.

In regard to your question about special HTML tags in HTML to do such things, we actually make use of the `<div>` for blocks and the `<span>` for inline text to offer special effects. These tags can have a class and thus your CSS can use the same trick as the form above. But that means you encapsulate things inside specific `<div>` and `<span>` tags:

```
<div class="form-xyz">
  <form>
    ...
  </form>
</div>

.form-xyz input { border: 2px solid red; }
```

As you can see, in this case the last CSS I presented earlier still works as expected!